# ajax update site from form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

As mentioned in this question [How can I check for live updates without using setInterval/timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112676/how-can-i-check-for-live-updates-without-using-setinterval-timeout)

I am aware of websockets, but im interested in maybe a more simplistic solution, could I effectively just let php update a key value pair file and have all pages update accordingly only if a value has changed?

eg. a bidding site where instead of polling for 100 or more items I only update the whole application when someone has essentially placed a bid , making it a one way flow 
**place bid->process form->update database->refresh all instances of said bid currently open in other windows** - hence the file that will store the info and maybe two way binding setup via angular template , or will caching be a issue?

how else do I update the views but all based on the action of someone placing a bid(submitting a form)?

Any ideas as to this approach?

Comment: __websocket__ is the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use websockets...

if you are new to socket.IO you can use some backend as a service like firebase, this should be really easy to implement.